# Topological proof without using invariance of domain

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

It is well known that if $X$ and $Y$ are closed, connected $n$-manifolds, then any embedding $f:X \to Y$ is surjective and so a homeomorphism. The standard way to see this is to notice that $f(X)$ must be both open (invariance of domain) and closed ($X$ is compact) in $Y$, hence the entire space since $Y$ is connected.

I'm wondering if there is a proof that does not make use of the rather sophisticated machinery of invariance of domain. The closest I can get is that if $f: X \to Y$ is a *smooth* embedding, then $f(X)$ must be open by the local submersion theorem. However, I can't see a way to transfer this to the topological category.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you describe the statement of invariance of domain briefly?

Comment: It is very unlikely that this can be done without invariance of domain or something very close to it.

Comment: I aggree with @PVAL.

Comment: Isn't invariance domain purely topological?

Comment: Maybe one could show that an embedding of closed compact manifolds induces an isomorphism on top level (co)homology? If, then, the embedding was not surjective, then it's image is a subspace of a punctured manifold, which deformation retracts onto a subspace of dimension one less than the manifold (hence represents a zero-map in (co)homology). The problem is, invariance of domain is probably easier to show than this isomorphism.

Comment: @DanRust: Why do we have such a deformation retraction when we're working with topological (not necessarily triangulable) manifolds? It seems to me you really want to have that $H_n$ of a noncompact manifold is zero, which seems harder than invariance of domain.